# Rails - Dynamic Collection Select value doesn't get posted with rest of the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm populating a collection select (located in a partial) based upon the value in another collection select.

The dynamic collection select values update like you would expect but when I submit the form the value is not present (note that the rest of the data from all of the rest of the form inputs does get passed through).

Since the data from the dynamic collection select is required, the controller redirects you back to the new view. Now since the value of the first dropdown is already selected (from the last time you tried to fill out the form) the dynamic dropdown is already loaded with the possible selections and now the value of the dynamic select is passed when the form is posted. If you change the value of the first collection select the second one will not post it's value until the second time around (as before).

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here are what I believe to be the relevant parts of my code:

Partial containing the dynamic collection select:

```
<%= collection_select(:f, :address_id, @addresses, :id, :concatenateAddress, {:include_blank => "Select an Address"}) %>
```

The New and Create actions in my controller:

```
def new
  @contact = Contact.new
  @companies = ContactCompany.all
  @addresses = []

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @contact }
  end
end

def create
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @contact.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Contact was successfully created.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@contact) }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @contact, :status => :created, :location => @contact }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @contact.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The parts in my view (showing both collection select boxes and my observe_field

```
<tr>
  <td colspan = "2">
    <%= 
      @company = ContactCompany.find(:all)
      f.collection_select(:company_id, @company, :id, :name,{:selected => @contact.company_id }) 
    %>
    <br/>
    <%= link_to 'Company Index', {:controller=>"contact_companies", :action=>"index"} %> | <%= link_to 'New Company', {:controller=>"contact_companies", :action=>"new"}%>
  </td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :phone_number %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :fax_number %></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan = "2">Address</td>
  <td>Cell Phone</td>
  <td>Alternate Phone</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan = "2">
  <% @addresses = ContactCompanyAddress.find(:all, :conditions=> {:company_id => @contact.company_id}) %>
  <%= observe_field "contact_company_id", :url=>{:controller => 'contact_companies', :action=>'ajax_get_addresses', :id => ContactCompany.first}, :with=> 'company_id' %>
  <div id="addresses"><%= render :partial => 'contact_companies/addresses', :object => @addresses, :f => 'f'%> </div>
  <%= link_to 'Address Index', {:controller=>"contact_company_addresses", :action=>"index"} %> | <%= link_to 'New Address', {:controller=>"contact_company_addresses", :action=>"new"}%>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Some additional information: I tested what I have in IE and the form works as expected. It has the above issue when I use Firefox or Safari. I also noticed that the parameter from the dynamic select box is not being posted with the rest of the form when this error occurs but I can't figure out why.

Comment: What does your partial in the addresses div look like?  Is everything wrapped properly in the form_for and end tags?